# Have I read the novel if I've forgotten the story?

Tags: present-perfect, past-perfect, past-vs-past-perfect, past-vs-present-perfect, answers

Imagine the following scenario:

I read a novel two years ago. Today I cannot remember the story of the novel any more, I've forgotten the story. Somebody asks me:

> Have you read the novel?

What should be my grammatical correct and natural sounding answer?

> Yes, **I've read** it but I've forgotten the story.
>    Yes, **I had read** it but I've forgotten the story.
>    No, **I had read** it but I've forgotten the story.
>    No, **I read** it but I've forgotten the story.

My uncertainty is due to the grammar explanations that *Present Perfect* indicates a state in the *present*. According to my Grammar book the following text is correct:

> Tom is looking for his key.
>   He **has lost** his key.
>   This means that he doesn't have it now.
>   Ten minutes later: < picture of Tom holding the key is his hand >
>   Now Tom **has found** his key.
>   He has it in his hand now.
>   **Has** he lost his key?
>   No, he **has found** it.
>   **Did** he **lose** his key?
>   Yes, he **did**.
>   He **lost** his key but now he **has found** it.

The present state of *having read a novel* is to know its story. But if after having read the novel I have forgotten its story then I am no more in this state although I was in this state before because I read the novel in the past.

Comment: "The present state of *having read a novel* is to know its story." I don't see why this is so. I *have* read War and Peace (many years ago), but I remember hardly anything about it. I *have* read the Bible, but I cannot recite it.

Comment: @Mick Shouldn't then be there another effect **in the present** of *having read "War and Peace" and the Bible* by you. What is it?

Comment: I recall having read it. That's all that "I have read *War and Peace*" says. How other people interpret the statement is their problem.

Comment: @Mick According to your explanation, the text from the Grammar book would be incorrect as long as Tom can recall having lost his key: "Has he lost his key? - Yes, he has found it, but he can recall having lost it."

Comment: I'm not a grammarian. If you asked me "Have you read War and Peace?", I would answer "Yes I have." Still, I remember a Physics professor of mine. If you asked him "Do you have the time?", he would always answer "Yes, thank you," and walk away. Maybe some of his attitude has rubbed off on me.

Comment: I think the question and answers above should be, "**Had he lost** his key?" "Yes, he **had**." "He **had lost** his key but now he has found it."

Answer (score 2):

The past perfect is not called for there, as you're referring to the *present* state of your memory, and to the fact of your having read the novel (once read, forever read) not to the state of your memory at some point in the past in relation to another time in the past.  You cannot remember the story *now*.

Either the simple past plus present perfect:

> I **read** the story (fifteen years ago) but **have forgotten** it.
>
> I **did read** the story but **have forgotten** it.

or the present perfect in both:

> I **have read** the story but **have forgotten** it.

To say that the present state of having read a novel is to know its story is like saying the present state of having met a person is to remember their name.

Comment: (a) Ok, the explanation why Past Perfect is not used here is clear, thx! Therefore, in my last sentence I should have written "although I **was**
 in this state before", right? (Btw a question about "not called for there". Is that with the phrasal "to call for"? Or is it "to call" with the prepositional object "for there"?) (b) What about "Yes" or "No"? In which case I should answer which? Or is it a special case of something inbetween? (c) What else would be the present state of having read a novel?

Comment: I'm confused about your questions. The Russian guy above has told you that it should be, "Yes, I have read the story, but have forgotten it."

Comment: I disagree with "I did read the story" unless the person should state "when": "I did read the story 15 years ago." Without knowing "when", it is "I have read the story."

Comment: @Nicholas Castagnola: **did** is an emphatic that makes perfectly good sense in the context of having forgotten:  I *did* read it, but I can't remember much of it.  There's no need for a time phrase.

Comment: It sounds off to me. I would emphatically say "have": "I **have** read it, but I've just forgotten what it's about." It probably is wrong with "did", but it's commonly said.

Comment: I simply don't see where you're coming from on this. There's absolutely nothing wrong with "I did read it".  It's like saying, "I did go to school today, pa, but I didn't pay attention to the teacher so I didn't learn anything".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo The explanation about the usage of **did** *does* make perfectly sense to me. But one point of my question has been left unclarified: should I answer "Yes", "No" or none of them both? (as mentioned in point b of my first comment).

Comment: *To call for* something => to demand or require something

Comment: There are two "actions" here, reading and forgetting. Let's not complicate it.  There is no "in between". Forget this bogus idea that reading necessarily involves remembering what you have read. Have you read the book? Yes.  Have you forgotten most of it? Yes.